# If linear operator $T^2 $has a cyclic vector then so does $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is my reasoning:

$T^2$ has a cyclic vector iff its minimal polynomial and its characteristic polynomial are equal.
Minimal polynomial of $T^2$ has degree $n$ . Therefore $T$ has an annihilating polynomial with degree $2n$ and with variables having even powers.

Since minimal polynomial of $T$ divides the annihilating polynomial having even powers, the powers of $x$ in minimal polynomial of $T$ will have the same parity. If minimal polynomial of $T$ is $q(x)$ and deg q(x) < n , $q(x)q(x)=p'(x^2)$ and p' is an annihilating polynomial of $T^2$ having deg < n which is a contradiction.

Is my reasoning is correct?

Comment: A simpler argument is $V=Z(v,T^2) \subseteq Z(v,T)$ implies  $V=Z(v,T)$ .

Comment: @lhf : I saw this answer but I wanted to know if its possible to use the minimal polynomial argument.

Comment: *"Since minimal polynomial of $T$ divides the annihilating polynomial having even powers, the powers of $x$ in minimal polynomial of $T$ will have the same parity."* Is this a well known statement about polynomials?

Comment: How can you guarantee that $q(x)q(x)$ will be of the form $p'(x^2)$?

Comment: Let's suppose for now that I accept your explanation for the first comment.  I'm still skeptical about that second one.  $q(x) = x^3 + 1$ leads to $q(x)q(x) = x^6 + 2x^3 + 1$, which is not a function of $x^2$.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom Anyway I saw my mistake. (x^2 -x)(x^2 +x) has odd powers cancelling out which I didn't take into consideration. isn't 1 x^0 which is even? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, $1$ is a degree zero polynomial

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I just got an idea based on my counterexample. Suppose $q(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$ and that deg q < n. Then I define $q'(x)$ as a polynomial equal to $q(x)$ except that the sign of coefficients of odd powers of $x$ is opposite. I think that the product $q'(x)q(x)$ will have all powers even and its degree is less than $2n$. Therefore if $p'(x^2) = q'(x)q(x)$, $p'(x)$ will be an annihilating polynomial of $T^2$ with degree less than n. So $T^2$ can't be cyclic.

Comment: In other words, you've taken $p'(x)=p(-x)$. I think that works. I don't understand why you insist on trying to do things this way, though.

Comment: What about the converse statement? I am having trouble figuring this out :/

Answer (score 6):

I don't understand why go through all the trouble. Vector $x$ is cyclic for $T$ if vectors $T^nx$ span whole space. Clearly, vectors of the form $T^{2n}x$ are a subset of these.

Comment: Is the converse true? If T has cyclic vector does T^2 automatically also have cyclic vector?

Comment: This is false. Take $T=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $T$ has a cyclic vector $(1,0)^T$, but $T^2=1$ so it doesn't have a cyclic vector.